# How to get dictionary keys without calculating the values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have existing code that defines a dictionary:

```
def func()
    ...
    map = {
      "aaa": expensive_operation1(),
      "bbb": expensive_operation2()
    }
```

I want to generate a list of the keys `list = ["aaa", "bbb"]` without having to execute the expensive value operations.

Of course, I could change the code like this:

```
KEY1 = "aaa"
KEY2 = "bbb"

LIST = [KEY1, KEY2]

def func()
    ...
    map = {
      KEY1: expensive_operation1(),
      KEY2: expensive_operation2()
    }
```

but then, if someone updates the dict with KEY3, they would have to remember to update both the dict and the LIST.

I'm open to any solution like lazy evaluations of the values, etc., just something maintainable and not error-prone.

Comment: `map.keys()` gives you an iterable of the dict's keys - you can apply `list()` to that if you really need a list, but that's seldom necessary.  (It's unclear whether you realize that *all* of the expensive operations have already been performed, when the dict was created.)

Comment: Declared like that, wouldn't the expensive operation be executed anyway, when you call func()?

Comment: sorry - I wasn't clear, apologies. I want to have access to LIST outside the scope of the function ```func()```. So this is a completely different function that needs to know the keys of that dictionary. I'm happy to refactor this code in any way so that information is available without having to execute ```func()``` and the expensive operations.

Comment: Can you put `expensive_operation`(s) as the values, without executing them? Something like `my_dict = {'aaa': expensive_operation1, 'bbb': expensive_operation2}` then only call the functions when you access the value: `result = my_dict['aaa']()`

Comment: Enhancement to @crunker99: Use a partial (from functools) as value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep `expensive_operation()` from executing, you need to enclose it in a function:

```
def func()
    ...
    map = {
      "aaa": lambda:expensive_operation1(),
      "bbb": lambda:expensive_operation2()
    }
```

This will prevent the actual call to `expensive_operation()` until `map["aaa"]` is called `map["aaa"]()`. You're free to do anything with the keys.